# Visual Studio Package Manager Console Can't run async code from C# dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, async-await

I have a very simple async method in a C# dll that I call from a powershell script.

When I run this in a powershell console window it runs as expected, or in a terminal window in Visual Studio (using WhackWhack).

The Package Manager Console Window, however, isn't able to run this (it just returns immediately). Is this a known limitation of the the PMC and is there any way around it?

(I need to use the PCM because I'm taking advantage of the [SolutionScripts](http://Solution%20Scripts%20https://www.nuget.org/packages/SolutionScripts/) package that allows Powershell to be shared at the solution level)

Comment: "When I run this in a powershell console window it runs as expected" -- but without waiting for the result, right? AFAIK PowerShell doesn't do anything special with a `Task` return value. If you want to wait for the result, tack a `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the end.

Comment: No - I have also wrapped my async method in a non-async method (with GetAwaiter/GetResult) which is called from the Powershell. This works fine in all other contexts apart from in the Package Manager Console (ergo, it runs Powershell differently)